# In mobile view we want to display div bottom of each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

In desktop view, output is proper but in mobile view we want to generate each div has its own description.

now my problem is that description display after all four elements and we want to display bottom of each div in mobile view.

Anyone help me with the help of any jQuery. I am trying to use offset and height with the help of jQuery but it is not work.

```js
$(".trust-datail").hide();
$(".trust-wrap").each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('id', +i);
});

$(".trust-datail").each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass("tab_" + i);
});

$(".trust-wrap").click(function () {
    $(".trust-datail").slideUp();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(".tab_" + id).is(':visible')) {
        $(".tab_" + id).slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $(".tab_" + id).slideDown();
    }
});
$(".close-new").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".trust-datail").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.trust-wrap {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.trust-wrap img {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.trust-wrap h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size:15px;
}
.trust-datail {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto auto 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.close-new {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.trust-datail h5 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.trust-datail p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="member_wrap">
    <div class="member_box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="8">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum1</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="9">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum2</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="10">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum3</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="11">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum4</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_8" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
          <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum1</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_9" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
          <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum2</h5>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_10" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
          <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum3</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_11" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
          <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum4</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated the Answer for you***

This will work for you.

What i did was made a function for you and called it in `$(window).load` and `$(window).resize` -

```
var cloneFun = function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 420) {
    $(".trust-datail").each(function(i) {
      var clonId = "#" + i,
        clon = $(this).clone();
      $(clonId).find('.clearfix').before(clon);
      $(this).addClass('mob-none');
    });
  } else {

    $(".trust-datail").removeClass('mob-none');
  }
};

$(window).load(function() {
  cloneFun();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  cloneFun();
});
```

This function checks the window size and if it's below `420px` it makes a clone of your div and paste it inside the `.trust-wrap`

and i use `.mob-none` to hide your details in mobile view.

```js
$(".trust-datail").hide();
$(".trust-wrap").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', +i);
});

$(".trust-datail").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("tab_" + i);
});


$(".trust-wrap").click(function() {
  $(".trust-datail").slideUp();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if ($(".tab_" + id).is(':visible')) {
    $(".tab_" + id).slideUp();
  } else {
    $(".tab_" + id).slideDown();
  }
});
$(".close-new").click(function() {
  $(this).parent(".trust-datail").slideUp();
});

var cloneFun = function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 420) {
    $(".trust-datail").each(function(i) {
      var clonId = "#" + i,
        clon = $(this).clone();
      $(clonId).find('.clearfix').before(clon);
      $(this).addClass('mob-none');
    });
  } else {

    $(".trust-datail").removeClass('mob-none');
  }
};

$(window).load(function() {
  cloneFun();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  cloneFun();
});
```

```css
.trust-wrap {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.trust-wrap img {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.trust-wrap h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.trust-datail {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto auto 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.close-new {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.trust-datail h5 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.trust-datail p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.mob-none {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="member_wrap">
    <div class="member_box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="8">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum1</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="9">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum2</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="10">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum3</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 chand">
          <div class="trust-wrap" id="11">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum4</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_8" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
        <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum1</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_9" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
        <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum2</h5>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_10" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
        <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum3</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
    <div class="trust-datail tab_11" style="display: none;">
      <div class="close-new">
        <img src="images/close-new.png">
      </div>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum4</h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have put the discriptions for you, i hope its helpfull for you. If there is anything else please do ask me.

Comment: the answer seems the same as the example in the question, what's different here?

Comment: this is not useful beacause description display twice.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the mobile screen width. I have updated the code.

Comment: still display twice in mobile view , first bottom of each div and second after all four div.

Comment: @ankitapatel please check again, I have put my code in a function, now it works well.

Comment: Please describe what you've done different here, to add more value to your answer.

Comment: @ankitapatel sorry for the delay had some other work to do, hope it was the answer you were looking for. if it is please do mark it as an answer :)

Comment: still there is some issue whenever i resize mobile to desktop , all clone div displayed. You have any solution for this..?

Comment: @ankitapatel so you don't want them to display on any screen.? if that's the case you can remove the `$(window).resize` function and `if` condition which checks the screen width - `if ($(window).width() <= 420) {}else{}`

Comment: @weBer   resize is not working . When i resize screen in mobile like 320 * 568, i want to reload it. Can you give any solution..?

Comment: @ankitapatel try if this is working in your Firefox.? - http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/mtJ2K/ [if it's working then there is any other error in your file] it's not firing please let me know.

Comment: @weBer pls check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k07ykz31/  I updated my code as i want but sometime in resize pls see cloning item there are too many clone is generating and not display properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154232/discussion-between-weber-and-ankita-patel).

Comment: @ankitapatel actually what are you looking for.?? are you trying to hide this in all screen width or only on mobile screen.?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the class "col-sm-3" to "col-md-3". So your html will be like below

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="member_wrap">
            <div class="member_box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 chand">
                        <div class="trust-wrap" id="8">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                            <h4>Lorem Ipsum1</h4>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 chand">
                        <div class="trust-wrap" id="9">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                            <h4>Lorem Ipsum2</h4>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 chand">
                        <div class="trust-wrap" id="10">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-250-250-9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                            <h4>Lorem Ipsum3</h4>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 chand">
                        <div class="trust-wrap" id="11">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                            <h4>Lorem Ipsum4</h4>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="trust-datail tab_8" style="display: none;">
                <div class="close-new">
                    <img src="images/close-new.png">
                </div>
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum1</h5>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            </div>
            <div class="trust-datail tab_9" style="display: none;">
                <div class="close-new">
                    <img src="images/close-new.png">
                </div>
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum2</h5>
                <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            </div>
            <div class="trust-datail tab_10" style="display: none;">
                <div class="close-new">
                    <img src="images/close-new.png">
                </div>
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum3</h5>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            </div>
            <div class="trust-datail tab_11" style="display: none;">
                <div class="close-new">
                    <img src="images/close-new.png">
                </div>
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum4</h5>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this is you are looking for. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: You are not understanding my question.

Comment: could you share an image, may be a rough sketch that you want to achieve in mobile screen?